# What is a good way to take fractional powers of a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math, matrix

I am working on a problem that involves taking fractional powers of particular matrices.

For the matrix A with 2 on the main diagonal and -1 on the sub and super diagonal (the finite difference matrix for the Dirichlet Laplacian in 1D), there was basically no difference between using MATLAB's `sqrtm(A)` function and diagonalizing the matrix (`A = V\D*V`) and computing `V\D^(1/2)*V` even if the matrix was as large as 1000x1000. This made me think I could compute other fractional powers `V\D^(1/n)*V` that MATLAB does not have built in functions for.

However when I consider the matrix A for the Dirichlet Laplacian in 2D, there is a significant difference between MATLAB's sqrtm function and the diagonalization procedure I used above even if the matrix was as small as 100x100. In particular, MATLAB's sqrtm function is better and my results don't make any sense if I do it the other way.

I am wondering if anyone can explain why this happens and if there is a way to fix it so that I can compute fractional powers of a large matrix in MATLAB.

**Edit: I made a big mistake since `A = V*D/V`, not `V\D*V` as I wrote above (and in my code). It turns out that MATLAB uses this algorithm for computing `A^(1/n)` by doing `V*D^(1/n)/V`. This was pointed out to me in the answer** [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16219/what-is-a-good-way-to-take-fractional-powers-of-a-matrix-in-matlab/16226#16226)

Comment: http://www.blackmesapress.com/Eigenvalues.htm have a look here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not talking about specific algorithms for the sparse matrices, it's just

```
expm(1.0/n*logm(A))
```

Comment: Thanks! Apparently A^(1/n) also works. This and your solution are both giving me matrices whose nth power differs from A by basically machine precision. I guess I didn't think it could be this easy, thanks again!